# How to search column name by partial string match and replace values in the column by dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

I need to search for column names based on partial strings and replace the column values from that of dictionary.

I am searching for partial column name string like so:

```
df.loc[df.columns.str.contains('column na')]
```

which works fine.

Now I want to replace values in the column that has been identified by partial string but with a dictionary values which I can do like this only on full column names:

```
di = {'a': 0, 'b': 1,'c':2,'d':3 }

df['column name'].replace(di,inplace=True)
```

How do I combine partial string search with replace?

I have tried this:

```
df = df.loc[df.columns.str.contains('column na')].replace(di, inplace=True)
```

but this replaces the entire df with the message `NoneType object of builtins module`

edit:

current df looks like this:

```
column1-adfas         column2-zdfsdf
a                            b
```

I want to be able to search and replace values from partial column name string like so:

```
column1-adfas         column2-zdfsdf
0                            1
```

Comment: can you show some examples of your columns and what values u expect?

Comment: @Datanovice I added some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, we can leverage `.map` however it only applies to series, so lets use an apply function, we can filter columns using `filter`

```
cols = df.filter(like='column').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x : x.map(di))
```

---

```
print(df)
     column1-adfas  column2-zdfsdf
0              0               1
```